# How to drag & drop an image over html page in android ?

Tags: android, html, image, drag-and-drop

I need to open a html page on android device and add an image dynamically to the page after clicking on a button. How do i do that ? Is it possible to drag & drop that image over html page? Please help me.

Comment: How do you drag and drop anything on Android...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints :

- Use a webview to host a webpage inside your app
- Use the webview.loadurl to load the content you want to use(image, html, ...)
- If you don't want to replace the content but add the image to whatever the content already is, use the scheme "javascript:" in the webview.loadurl to launch javascript on the hosted page and make it do whatever you want.
- Once you have some code and something specific to ask, come back here and do so.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yahel. I will come back with more specific question.